# Unable to set the Title of the Dialog using SetDlgItemTextW() in MFC Dialog Based application

Tags: mfc

My Requirement Is:

I am using MFC Dialog Based application and here I want to set the title of the dialog with Japanese string.

Below is my code snippet:

```
CStringW str;   // Using CStringW to support unicode characters

CTestofUTF83Dlg dlg;   // CTestofUTF83Dlg is my dialog class that is derived    
                      //from CDialog

str.LoadString(IDC_TESTJAPAN); // IDC_TESTJAPAN contains my Japanese string

SetDlgItemTextW(dlg,IDD_TESTOFUTF83_DIALOG,str); // IDD_TESTOFUTF83_DIALOG is the ID of my Dialog
```

With the above code, the Dialog box Title is not reflecting the Japanese string.

I think it is due to the first parameter of the SetDlgItemTextW, i.e., Handle to the dialog (dlg).

Because, if I use `SetDlgItemText()` function I am able to set the title.

Please Help me.

Comment: Have you debugged to see that your LoadString does indeed put the desired string in str?

Comment: @weisman.. Yes, LoadString is placing desired string in str.

Comment: Is the function returning a value indicating success?

Comment: @o_weisman.. Yes it is indicating success and the problem is only with this line SetDlgItemTextW(dlg,IDD_TESTOFUTF83_DIALOG,str); Because if i use the message box to test by using MessageBoxW(dlg,str,0,0); it is working fine and displaying the string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that won't work.  You have not created your window/dialog yet so it does not have a window handle (m_hWnd != 0 or garbage).

Call SetWindowText inside the OnInitDialog() member of your CTestofUTF83Dlg.

```
BOOL CTestofUTF83Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
   CDialog::OnInitDialog();
   // SetWindowText .... blah blah
   return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: i have included in the OnInitDialog, but still it is not working.

Comment: Based on your username, it doesn't sound Japanese...which is not an issue with me, but ...  Do you have the Japanese locale installed to Windows?

Secondly, are you building your App as Unicode?  Make sure you build it as Unicode if you have to mix fonts!!!!  If you build it as MBCS and your default code page is not Japanese, you will have problems.